# Mavericks system Ruby and gem broken

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-mavericks

When I tried to run `ruby -v` or `gem -v` (or any other command), I get:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib
```

This is after I ran `rvm system` to temporally switch to the system default Ruby. RVM is working fine, but I have a special need to install a gem to the system Ruby and I can't because of this problem.

Does anyone know why? It seems to be some kind of link problem to Ruby, but I'm don't know how to solve this.

I ran `which ruby` and it's at this point located in "/usr/local/bin/ruby".

I checked the Ruby in "/usr/lib/" and it's pointing to my system Ruby: "../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ruby"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not running the system Ruby; that's in `/usr/bin/ruby`. Since you're running `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, I'm guessing that you're using Homebrew, since that's where it puts Ruby. It's very possible that Mavericks broke your Homebrew install; I had to reinstall a lot of MacPorts myself. If you're not using Homebrew, that Ruby came from some other non-Apple source and you'll likely have to reinstall it.

Comment: The system Ruby shouldn't be in /usr/local/bin, it should be in /usr/bin. /usr/local is reserved for non-vendor-supplied code, meaning stuff you added on a Mac. *WHY* do you need to add something to the system Ruby? The whole point of RVM is that you never need to touch the system, you leave it as Apple, or the OS vender, wanted it.

Comment: Jim, I'm runnning homebrew. Brew is working fine, so, something else is broken then? Not sure how to find/fix this. Tin Man, I was trying to use an app called CodeKit. I need it to point to external gem executables, and it refuses point to gems installed by rvm. It needs to use gems installed by the system ruby.

Comment: Jim, I figured it out, thank you. When you said reinstall, I thought you meant homebrew. Then I realised you meant Ruby, so I reinstalled and did a force link, the error messages went away. Still can't figure out how to run the system default one though… trying modifying ~/.bash_profile $PATH, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Mavericks broke the homebrew installed Ruby. I just need to reinstall and force link it to make the error message go away.

In case anyone is interested, for CodeKit to work correctly using an external compass executable, just find your compass file, copy it over to /usr/bin, and point to it in the app.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I changed the symbolic link for libruby back to lib ruby.1.8.6.dylib

```
$ sudo cp -p /usr/local/lib/libruby.1.8.6.dylib /usr/lib
$ cd /usr/lib
$ sudo rm libruby.dylib
$ sudo ln -s libruby.1.8.6.dylib libruby.dylib
```

If you need to go back to Ruby 2.0

```
$ sudo rm libruby.dylib
$ sudo ln -s libruby.2.0.0.dylib libruby.dylib
```