# Basic Homebrew installation line fails on 10.9

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I cannot install Homebrew with the line from the website:

```
$ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
```

I always get the error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I get the same errors when I type ruby -v or ruby --version. I am at a complete loss of what to do--I can't install ruby without homebrew, which fails, but I can't install homebrew directly, either. Total newbie, totally lost!

Comment: what `shell` you use? `bash` or something.

Comment: This is just using the Mac OS X 10.9 Terminal.

Comment: have you installed `rvm` or `rbenv`?

Comment: Yes, RVM. The command which ruby returned /usr/local/bin/ruby, which is not where it's supposed to be according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803736/mavericks-system-ruby-and-gem-broken). That post didn't really say what to do, so I just deleted it, and now Homebrew seems to be installing OK?

Comment: have PATH in `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: my .bash_profile file just says:

    `source ~/.profile`

    `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`